# How to get image from canvas by using fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using fabric js to add text on images but the problem is i am unable download the final image from canvas.I am geting the base64 url while prinitng dataUrl but not geting the image URL .Please find the below code snipet.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" ></canvas>
<script>
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
    // load image
    fabric.Image.fromURL('https://pixlr.com/photo/image-editing-2-3-pw.jpg', function (img) {
        img.scaleToWidth(100);
        img.scaleToHeight(100);
        // create text
        var text = new fabric.Text('hello world', {
            left: 70,
            top: 80,
            fontSize: 15,
            fontFamily: 'Arial',
            fill: '#fff',
            backgroundColor:'#08976d',
            borderColor:'#078b64',
            fontWeight:400,
            padding:50
        });

        // add image and text to a group
        var group = new fabric.Group([img, text], {
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
        });
        // add the group to canvas
        canvas.add(group);
    });

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    var imgUrl = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/[^;]/, 'data:application/octet-stream');
    console.log(dataURL);
</script>
```

Comment: try it inside `function (img) {` function

Comment: could you please elaborate little more or share your code

Comment: i have tried inside that image function also getting error 
fabric.js:11383 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Comment: it may be because of crossorigin issue.just check if it's working with images in your source folder .https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/issues/258.

Comment: take my code to fiddle you will get to know

Comment: see this fidler  https://jsfiddle.net/59132L04/ .you just need to enable cross origin accessibility

Answer (score 1):

If your main purpose is just to download the dataURL file then you don't actually need the image url. As the image is not physically present on any server it doesn't have an image url path. You can do something like this to download the file

```
function downloadFile(uri, name) {
  let link = document.createElement("a"); //creates link element
  link.download = name; //sets name of the file
  link.href = uri; //sets the datauri as the data source of the file
  document.body.appendChild(link); //adds it to the dom
  link.click(); //trigger a click event
  document.body.removeChild(link); //removes it from the dom
  delete link; //optional: delete the reference of it from memory
}
downloadFile("data:text/html,HelloWorld!", "helloWorld.txt"); //to call above code
```

Comment: You want to download the image from the canvas' dataURL. So just use this function and place your dataURL string and desired file name with extension. I'll make this clear to you, once you edit the image in fabric.js and want to get the edited image you have to use the dataURL of it. You will not get the image url of edited image. You can also display that dataURL image like shown in the other example.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to get an image with the text
you can instantiate an **Image** and set the **src** value with `canvas.toDataURL('image/png');`, then you can wait for **onload** as the next example:

```
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    img.onload = function(): void {
       console.log('you have an image with text');
    };
```

Comment: i want image url not text

Comment: You want an image url to download, like a link?

Comment: If that what you want this could be useful https://www.sanwebe.com/snippet/downloading-canvas-as-image-dataurl-on-button-click

Comment: that's the problem that toDataUrl returning base64 format

Comment: if you want to download an image you can use the link example, else if you want to show an image you can use my sample

Comment: the image is coming blank

Comment: How do you apply this to an <img> element in your HTML ?